# How to entirely clear a pallet storage on a living chain?

Tags: pallet, runtime, storage, contracts

Would it be possible to clear a pallet storage with a call on a live chain ?

Precisely I would like to remove all contracts and code hash existing on my chain (as sudo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be challenging to achieve that with a call.

You will need to send numerous extrinsics to accomplish it.

---

I suggest performing a runtime upgrade.

Refer to this link for more information: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/migration/fn.clear_storage_prefix.html

```rs
use frame_support::migration;

migration::clear_storage_prefix(b"module name", &[], &[], None, None);
```

If your pallet storage is extensive, it is advisable to review the documentation mentioned above and adjust the values of `None` according to your specific situation.

Comment: Okay thanks ! What about weights on that function ? I need to return the used weights when doing a runtime upgrade and clear_storage_prefix() doesn’t calculate any weights used so do I need to check how many iterations was done and calculate weights from it ?

Comment: You could count the delections and return the weight `T::DbWeights::writes(x)`.